# Частичная подмена изображения, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, изображения, цвета

есть задача симулировать раскрашивание определнного предмета на картинке в определнный цвет, изначально хотел взять 2 изображения (начальное и конечное) и положить их друг на друга, после чего по мере раскрашивания пользователем поднимать пиксели одного изображения над другим, только что-то бред какой-то, в общем направьте ктонибудь в нужное русло) может библиотеки какие есть для работы с изображениями или что, а то чет я туповат.

Comment: CANVAS -  и этим все сказано....  Ничего лучше  не найдешь...

Comment: Используй html5 CANVAS. Это основной способ работы с графикой

Comment: Что бы говорить более предметно, покажите изображения, какие надо красить. Как раскрасить? Это должен быть эффект раскрашивания карандашом, кисточкой или просто плавное проявление цвета? В общем, дайте больше информации.

Comment: Попробою оконкретить: 1.Изображение - могут быть разными например на столе лежит кепка зеленого цвета, нужно сделать ее красной. 2. Раскрашивание просто точка с радиусом в несколько пикселей, но не полная заливка, а именно смена цвета кепки, чтобы остались все ее швы и т.д. близко к этому есть заливка в фотошопе.

Comment: я конечно понимаю что это не то , но вроде бы можно цвет кепки так извратить , https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/bMrRyp в песочницы оригинал фото по ссылке - для проверки цвета